# Titanium get navigation group from file

Tags: navigation, titanium

I'm making a Titanium app for my school, and I use navigation groups to navigate between the windows. I opened a window from a file, like this:

```
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
         title: "Test window",
         url: "file.js
    });
```

But now I want to open a window from "file.js", but how do I open it from my navigation group?

Comment: this the completely the wrong way to build your app using the platform. I suggest you take a look at the latest documentation for best practices

Comment: I am not just a beginner or something, I make apps for a long time now, this is just a question. What's wrong with using a navigation group?

Comment: creating application windows by passing in an url is not a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create navigationWindow with latest titanium mobile sdk.

look at the online doc.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
navGroup.open(win);
```

Thanks